# How to get id from link using js

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I'm using wschat wordpress plugin. I'm passing link with the conversation id. If there is conversation id we need to get id and activate the particular user conversation.
I'm passing link as https://brookstone220.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wschat_chat&cid=3
and the js file will bw:
admin_chat.js:

```
import {WSChat, formatDate} from './chat';
import { AdminApiConnector } from './admin_api_connector';
import { AdminPusherConnector } from './admin_pusher_connector';
import { EVENTS } from './events';
import { EmojiButton } from '@joeattardi/emoji-button';
import UserMetaInfo from './components/user_meta_info.html'

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    const wrapper = jQuery('.wschat-wrapper');

    if (wrapper.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
   
    const CONVERSATION_TEMPLATE = `
        <div class="friend-drawer friend-drawer--onhover" data-conversation-id="{{CONVERSATION_ID}}">
          <img class="profile-image" src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?rounded=true&name=Guest" alt="">
          <div class="text">
            <h6>{{NAME}}</h6>
            <p class="last-message text-truncate">{{LAST_MESSAGE}}</p>
          </div>
          <span class="time small d-none">{{TIMESTAMP}}</span>
          <span class="unread-count badge rounded-pill align-self-center">{{UNREAD_COUNT}}</span>
        </div>
        <hr>`;

    const CHAT_BUBBLE_TEMPLATE = `
          <div class="row g-0 w-100 message-item" data-message-id="{{MESSAGE_ID}}">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-9 col-lg-6 {{OFFSET}}">
              <div class="chat-bubble chat-bubble--{{POS}}">
                {{CONTENT}}
              </div>
              <span class="time">{{TIMESTAMP}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>`;

    const CONVERSATION_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS = {
        '{{CONVERSATION_ID}}': '',
        '{{LAST_MESSAGE}}': 'left',
        '{{TIMESTAMP}}': '',
        '{{NAME}}': '',
    };

    const BUBBLE_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS = {
        '{{OFFSET}}': '',
        '{{POS}}': 'left',
        '{{CONTENT}}': '',
        '{{TIMESTAMP}}': '',
        '{{MESSAGE_ID}}': '',
    };

    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        data: {
            wschat_ajax_nonce: wschat_ajax_obj.nonce
        }
    });

    var chat = new WSChat(jQuery('.wschat-wrapper'), {
        connector: wschat_ajax_obj.settings.communication_protocol === 'pusher' ? AdminPusherConnector : AdminApiConnector,
        api: {
            endpoint: wschat_ajax_obj.ajax_url,
            interval: 3000,
            wschat_ajax_nonce: wschat_ajax_obj.nonce,
            pusher: {
                key: wschat_ajax_obj.settings.pusher.app_key,
                cluster: wschat_ajax_obj.settings.pusher.cluster,
            }
        },
        alert: {
            url: wschat_ajax_obj.settings.alert_tone_url
        },
        header: {
            status_text: wschat_ajax_obj.settings.widget_status === 'online' ? wschat_ajax_obj.settings.header_online_text : wschat_ajax_obj.settings.header_offline_text,
        }
    });

    if (wschat_ajax_obj.settings) {
        for(let key in wschat_ajax_obj.settings.colors) {
            key && chat.$el.get(0).style.setProperty(key,  '#' +wschat_ajax_obj.settings.colors[key]);
        }
    }

    setInterval(() => {
        chat.connector.start_conversation();
    }, 5000);

    const chat_panel = chat.$el.find('.chat-panel');
    const conversation_panel = chat.$el.find('.conversation-list');
    const chat_panel_header = chat.$el.find('.chat-panel-header');
    const chat_tray_box = chat.$el.find('.chat-box-tray');
    const message_input = jQuery('#wschat_message_input');
    const MESSAGE_INFO = {
        min: 0,
        max: 0,
    };
    let PAST_REQUEST_IS_PENDING = false;
    let SCROLL_PAUSED = false;
    let DISABLE_SCROLL_LOCK = false;
    const SCROLL_OFFSET = 100;


    const replaceConversation = (conversation) => {
        let item = conversation_panel.find('[data-conversation-id='+conversation.id+']');
        if (item.length === 0 ) {
            return false;
        }

        item.find('.time').text(conversation.updated_at);
        item.find('.last-message').text( conversation.recent_message ? conversation.recent_message.body.text : '');
        item.find('.unread-count').text(conversation.unread_count || '');

        if (conversation.is_user_online) {
            item.addClass('online');
        } else {
            item.removeClass('online');
        }

        return true;
    };

    const sortConversation = () => {
        const new_conversation_panel = conversation_panel.clone();
        const items = [];

        new_conversation_panel.find('[data-conversation-id]').each(function (i, item) {
            items.push(item);
        });

        items.sort((a, b) => {
            let timestamp1 = jQuery(a).find('.time').html();
            let timestamp2 = jQuery(b).find('.time').html();

            return strToDate(timestamp2) - strToDate(timestamp1);
        });

        new_conversation_panel.html('');

        items.forEach((item) => {
            new_conversation_panel.append(item);
        });

        conversation_panel.html(new_conversation_panel.html());
    };

    const strToDate = (timestamp) => {
        let [date1, time1] = timestamp.split(' ');
        date1 = date1.split('-');
        time1 = time1.split(':');

        return parseInt(date1.join('') + time1.join(''));
    };

    const showNoConversation = () => {
        const no_conversation_alert = jQuery('.no-conversation-alert');
        conversation_panel.append(no_conversation_alert.removeClass('d-none'));
    }

    chat.on(EVENTS.WSCHAT_ON_NO_CONVERSATIONS, () => {
        showNoConversation();
    });
    chat.on(EVENTS.WSCHAT_ON_FETCH_CONVERSATIONS, (conversations) => {

        conversations.forEach(conversation => {
            if (replaceConversation(conversation)) {
                return;
            }

            CONVERSATION_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS['{{CONVERSATION_ID}}'] = conversation.id;
            CONVERSATION_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS['{{NAME}}'] = conversation.user.meta.name;
            CONVERSATION_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS['{{TIMESTAMP}}'] = formatDate(conversation.updated_at);
            CONVERSATION_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS['{{LAST_MESSAGE}}'] = conversation.recent_message ? conversation.recent_message.body.text : '';
            CONVERSATION_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS['{{UNREAD_COUNT}}'] = conversation.unread_count || '';

            let row_template = CONVERSATION_TEMPLATE;

            row_template = row_template.replace(new RegExp(Object.keys(CONVERSATION_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS).join('|'), 'g'), match => CONVERSATION_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS[match]);

            row_template = jQuery(row_template);

            if (conversation.is_user_online) {
                row_template = row_template.addClass('online');
            }

            if (conversation.user && conversation.user.meta.avatar) {
                row_template.find('img.profile-image').attr('src', conversation.user.meta.avatar)
            }
            conversation_panel.append(row_template);
        });

        sortConversation();

        setTimeout(() => {
            let activeItem = conversation_panel.find('.active[data-conversation-id]').length
            activeItem === 0 && conversation_panel.find('[data-conversation-id]').eq(0).click();
        }, 1000);
    });

    chat.on(EVENTS.WSCHAT_ON_SET_CONVERSATION, (data) => {
        data.user &&
            chat_panel_header.find('.username').text(data.user.meta.name);
        let info = chat.$el.find('.user-meta-info').html(UserMetaInfo);

        chat_panel_header.parent().removeClass('d-none')

        info.find('.name').html(data.user.meta.name);
        info.find('.browser').html(data.user.meta.browser);
        info.find('.os').html(data.user.meta.os);
        info.find('.device').html(data.user.meta.device);
        info.find('.url').html(data.user.meta.current_url);

        message_input.focus();
        MESSAGE_INFO.min = 0;
        MESSAGE_INFO.max = 0;
        DISABLE_SCROLL_LOCK = true;
        resizeChat();

        setTimeout(() => DISABLE_SCROLL_LOCK = false, 1000);
    });

    chat.on(EVENTS.WSCHAT_ON_FETCH_MESSAGES, (data) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.messages.length; i++) {
            let row = data.messages[i];

            if (row.is_agent === true) {
                BUBBLE_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS['{{OFFSET}}'] = 'offset-lg-6 offset-md-3 offset-xs-2';
                BUBBLE_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS['{{POS}}'] = 'right';
            } else {
                BUBBLE_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS['{{OFFSET}}'] = '';
                BUBBLE_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS['{{POS}}'] = 'left';
            }
            BUBBLE_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS['{{MESSAGE_ID}}'] = row.id;
            BUBBLE_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS['{{CONTENT}}'] = row.body.formatted_content;
            BUBBLE_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS['{{TIMESTAMP}}'] = formatDate(row.created_at);

            let row_template = CHAT_BUBBLE_TEMPLATE;

            row_template = row_template.replace(new RegExp(Object.keys(BUBBLE_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS).join('|'), 'g'), match => BUBBLE_TEMPLATE_DEFAULTS[match]);

            if (MESSAGE_INFO.min === 0) {
                chat_panel.append('<span data-message-id="0"></span>');
            }

            if (MESSAGE_INFO.min > row.id) {
                chat_panel.find('[data-message-id='+MESSAGE_INFO.min+']').before(row_template);
                MESSAGE_INFO.min = row.id;
            }

            if (MESSAGE_INFO.max === 0 || MESSAGE_INFO.max < row.id) {
                chat_panel.find('[data-message-id='+MESSAGE_INFO.max+']').after(row_template);
                MESSAGE_INFO.max = row.id;
                scrollIfNotPaused();
            }

            if (MESSAGE_INFO.min === 0) {
               scrollIfNotPaused();
            }

            MESSAGE_INFO.min = MESSAGE_INFO.min || row.id;
            MESSAGE_INFO.max = MESSAGE_INFO.max || row.id;
        }

        if (DISABLE_SCROLL_LOCK === true) {
            scrollIfNotPaused();
        }

    });

    chat.on(EVENTS.WSCHAT_ON_PONG, (data) => {
        let drawer = chat_panel_header.find('.friend-drawer');
        let row_template = conversation_panel.find('[data-conversation-id='+data.id+']');
        let row_unread_count = row_template.find('.unread-count');
        let header_unread_count = chat_panel_header.find('.unread-count');

        chat_panel_header.find('.status').text(data.status);
        header_unread_count.text(data.unread_count);
        row_unread_count.text(data.unread_count || '');

        if (data.unread_count) {
            header_unread_count.removeClass('d-none');
        } else {
            header_unread_count.addClass('d-none');
        }

        if (data.is_online) {
            drawer.addClass('online');
            row_template.addClass('online');
        } else {
            drawer.removeClass('online');
            row_template.removeClass('online');
        }
    });

    const scrollIfNotPaused = () => {
        if (SCROLL_PAUSED === false || DISABLE_SCROLL_LOCK === true) {
            chat_panel[0].scrollTop = chat_panel[0].scrollHeight;
        }
    }

    const send_btn = jQuery('#wschat_send_message').on('click', function() {
        let msg = message_input.val();

        if (msg.trim() === '' && chat.trigger(EVENTS.WSCHAT_CAN_SEND_EMPTY_MESSAGE, false, true) === false) {
            return false;
        }

        chat.sendMessage({
            // Type is text by default now, it needs to changed based on the selection content
            wschat_ajax_nonce: wschat_ajax_obj.nonce,
            type: 'text',
            'content[text]': message_input.val()

        });
        message_input.val('').focus();
    });

    message_input.keyup(function(e) {
        e.key === 'Enter' && send_btn.click();
    });

    message_input.on('focus', function() {
        let unread_count = chat_panel_header.find('.unread-count').text();

        if (parseInt(unread_count) > 0) {
            chat.trigger(EVENTS.WSCHAT_ON_READ_ALL_MESSAGE);
        }
    });

    chat_panel_header.on('click', '.user-meta-info-toggle', function () {
        chat.$el.find('.conversation-wrapper .user-meta-info').toggleClass('d-none');
    });

    conversation_panel.on('click', '[data-conversation-id]', function() {
        chat_panel.html('');
        let item = jQuery(this);
        let converssation_id = item.data('conversation-id');
        conversation_panel.find('[data-conversation-id]').removeClass('active');
        item.addClass('active')
        chat.connector.join_conversation(converssation_id);
    });

    chat_panel.on('scroll', function () {
        if (DISABLE_SCROLL_LOCK) {
            SCROLL_PAUSED = false;
            return;
        }
        if (this.scrollTop < SCROLL_OFFSET) {
            if (PAST_REQUEST_IS_PENDING === false) {
                PAST_REQUEST_IS_PENDING = true;
                chat.connector.get_messages({
                    after: 0,
                    before: MESSAGE_INFO.min
                });
                setTimeout(() => PAST_REQUEST_IS_PENDING = false, 500);
            }
        }

        if (this.offsetHeight + this.scrollTop >= this.scrollHeight - SCROLL_OFFSET) {
            SCROLL_PAUSED = false;
        } else {
            SCROLL_PAUSED = true;
        }
    });

    const resizeChat = () => {
        const window_height = jQuery(window).height() - chat.$el.offset().top;

        const height = window_height - (
            chat_panel_header.height()*2 + chat_tray_box.height()
        );

        conversation_panel.css({
            'min-height': height + 'px'
        });

        chat_panel.css({
            'min-height': height + 'px'
        });
    };

    jQuery(window).resize(() => resizeChat());
    resizeChat();

    const emojiPicker = document.getElementById('wschat_emoji_picker');
    const emoji = new EmojiButton({
        style: 'twemoji',
        rootElement: emojiPicker.parentElement,
        position: 'top'
    });


    emojiPicker.addEventListener('click', function() {
        emoji.togglePicker();
    });

    emoji.on('emoji', function(selection) {
        console.log(selection)
        message_input.val(message_input.val() + selection.emoji).focus();
        setTimeout(() => message_input.focus(), 500)
    });


    // Attachment toggler
    chat.$el.find('#attachment_picker').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        chat.$el.find('.attachment-list').toggleClass('show d-none');
    });
    chat.$el.find('.attachment-list').on('click','button', function () {

        chat.$el.find('#attachment_picker').click();
    });

});
```

Can someone help me on this? How to get id using this js file and activate the conversation?

Comment: *How to get id* ... what id? you say "I'm passing link with the conversation id" ... so you have some sort of id, but what id are you trying to get, and where does it come from?

Comment: I'm passing id in link https://brookstone220.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wschat_chat&cid=3  Here cid is i'm passing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I used for my project to get URL parameters.

```js
var getParameter = function getParameter(param) {
    var pageURL = window.location.search.substring(1), // Get current URL substrings
        urlVars = pageURL.split('&'),                  // Split on all "&" for more than one.
        parameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < urlVars.length; i++) {
        // Get the value of the parameter. 
        parameterName = urlVars[i].split('=');         
        
        // Return the value of the parameter if it has the same name as param
        if (parameterName[0] === param) {
            return typeof parameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(parameterName[1]);
        }
    }
    return false;
};

var cID = getParameter('cid');
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. But, i don't know how to check whether it's getting id or not.  I have tried alert and console.log but it's not working. Can you please help me on that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but I can try to help, if it gets the conversation ID it will return it, so with your URL it would return "3", but if it can't find cid in the URL anywhere it will simply return false.

Comment: Hi, this is javascript or jquery

Comment: Hey Salini, this is just written in plain JavaScript.